# Showing a loading image on page refresh

Tags: jquery, refresh, loading

I have a javascript snippet that forces a page reload using .reload(true) once someone clicks on a particular link. How can I show a simple "loading" image while the page refresh is taking place?

(Already using jquery on the page if that helps)

Answer (score 1):

Check out [jquery-loadmask plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-loadmask/)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify where you wanted the loading image. If you want the images themselves to "become" a loading image, start by decorating your images as so:

```
<img class="cl"
     src="loading.gif"
     onload="if(!this._done){this._done=true;this.src='real.jpg';}"/>
```

Then, before calling `.reload`, do:

```
$('img.cl').attr('src','loading.gif');
```

On the other hand, if you want to put it in a fixed place, simply do so, but mark that div as hidden, as in:

```
<div id="rl">loading <img src="loading.gif"/></div>
<noscript><style>
#rl {display:none;}
</style></noscript>
<script><!--
document.write("<style>\ndiv#rl {display:block;}\n</style>");
$('#rl').hide();
//--></script>
```

(maybe you'll also position rl someplace)

Then, before calling reload, simply re-show it:

```
$('#rl').show();
```